# Return the count of the number of times that the two elements in two different arrays differ by 2 or less, but are not equal

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, operators

While I was practicing Java problems on coding bat I came across the following problem statement.

Problem:-

> Given two arrays nums1 and nums2 of the same length, for every element in
> nums1, consider the corresponding element in nums2 (at the same
> index). Return the count of the number of times that the two elements
> differ by 2 or less, but are not equal.

Example:-

```
matchUp([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 10]) → 2
matchUp([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 5]) → 3
matchUp([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3]) → 2
```

My Solution:-

```
public int matchUp(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
  int count=0;
  for(int i=0;i<=nums1.length-1;i++){
    if((nums1[i]-nums2[i]==1)||(nums1[i]-nums2[i]==2)||(nums2[i]-nums1[i]==1)||(nums2[i]-nums1[i]==2))
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

My Question:-

Though I have solved this question, my solution looks a bit long. So I am looking for some shorter and accurate solutions with fewer lines of code than mine. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.abs` to get difference when compare

You can use Stream API

```
return IntStream.range(0, nums1.length).map(i -> Math.abs(nums1[i]-nums2[i]))
                .filter(i -> i==2 ||i ==1).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using API, Just an additional answer to the amazing one given by @Eklavya

```
public static int matchUp(int a[], int b[]){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        int diff = Math.abs(a[i]-b[i]);
        if(diff>0 && diff<=2)
           count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution passes all the tests on ***CodingBat***:

```
public int matchUp(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
  int counter = 0;
  int difference = 0;
  
   for (int i = 0; i < nums1.length; i++) {
     if (nums1[i] != nums2[i]) {
       difference = Math.abs(nums1[i] - nums2[i]);
       if (difference <= 2) {
         counter++;
       }
     }
   }
  
  return counter;
}
```